# nested switch case error with wrong output?

Tags: java, nested, output

I am experiencing some problems with the output of my program. I am certain the error is logical but i just cant fix it. error should be somewhere around here

```
 String plusorminus ="+-"; 

char mark = plusorminus.charAt(0);
char modifier = 0;

if(plusorminus.length() >= 1)
{
    modifier = plusorminus.charAt(1);
}

/*This is my utility scanner,
 * I created char grade to get the user input.
 */
java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
String userInputString = input.nextLine();
char grade = userInputString.charAt(0);
```

I don't know how to fix it. At the moment if i insert A+ to the program it would give me the result for A-. Heres my full code.

```
public class SwitchCase {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.println("Please enter your grade (ex.A+) to get the mark range");

/*This block of codes converts from string to
 * char and it gets the plus or minus sign
 */
String plusorminus ="+-"; 

char mark = plusorminus.charAt(0);
char modifier = 0;

if(plusorminus.length() >= 1)
{
    modifier = plusorminus.charAt(1);
}

/*This is my utility scanner,
 * I created char grade to get the user input.
 */
java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
String userInputString = input.nextLine();
char grade = userInputString.charAt(0);

/*This set of code contains the nested switch statements
 * that i will use to output the correct mark range
 * to the user. It also contains a try statement to find runtime
 * errors in the program.
 */
try{
switch(grade)
{
    case 'A':
        switch(modifier)
        {
            case '+': System.out.println("Your grade is 90-99.99%"); break;
            case '-': System.out.println("Your grade is 80-84.99%"); break;
            default: System.out.println("Your grade is 85-89.99%"); break;
        }
        break;
    case 'B':
        switch(modifier)
        {
           case'+': System.out.println("Your grade is 77.00 - 79.99%"); break;
           case'-': System.out.println("Your grade is 70.00 - 72.99%"); break;
           default: System.out.println("Your grade is 73.00 - 76.99%"); break;
        }
        break;   
    case 'C':
        switch(modifier)
         {
           case'+': System.out.println("Your grade range is 67.00 - 69.99%"); break;
           case'-': System.out.println("Your grade range is 60.00 - 62.99%"); break;
           default: System.out.println("Your grade range is 63.00 - 66.99%"); break;
         }
         break;
    case 'D':
         switch(modifier)
         {
           case'+': System.out.println("Your grade range is 55.00 - 59.99%"); break;
           case'-': System.out.println("-"); break;
           default: System.out.println("Your grade range is 50.00 - 54.99%"); break;
         }
         break;
    case 'F':
         switch(modifier)
         {
           default: System.out.println("Your grade range is 0.00-49.99%"); break;
          }    
         break;
        }
}
catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) { //if the above error is met, message will be sent to the user
               System.out.println("Please enter a valid grade!");
         }
input.close(); //ends the user input
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `modifier = plusorminus.charAt(1);` do? When does it execute?

Comment: Is there no 'E' grade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
char grade = userInputString.charAt(0);
```

add

```
char modifier = ' ';
if( userInputString.length() > 1 ){
    modifier = userInputString.charAt(1);
}
```

and remove the code dealing with plusorminus.

You should also add some code to avoid hiccups after reading the input line.

```
userInputString = userInputString.trim(); // maybe user hits space?
if( ! userInputString.matches( "^[A-F][-+]?$" ) ){
    // error message...
}
```

Not sure whether there is E, and F+ or F-?? We have different grades. Perhaps the regex should be

```
"^[A-E][-+]?|F$"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be inserting

```
A+
```

but you're only consuming the `A`.

```
String userInputString = input.nextLine();
char grade = userInputString.charAt(0);
```

The `modifier` is assigned, deterministically, here

```
String plusorminus ="+-"; 

char mark = plusorminus.charAt(0);
char modifier = 0;

if(plusorminus.length() >= 1)
{
    modifier = plusorminus.charAt(1);
}
```

The length of `plusorminus` will always be `2` which means that `modifier` will always be `plusorminus.charAt(1)`, ie. `-`. You want to assign the second character of your input string as the `modifier`.